# error de cannot find symbol

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me da este error  es muy extraño, ya que parece de paquetes pero si cambio el paquete y pongo la ubicación me salta un error, he probado de todo y me pone que no me detecta la clase Aparcabicicletas, motivo por el cual el Set no me funciona, pero no me lo detecta como error, es muy raro, si alguien me puede ayudar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy introduciendo en una coleccion datos de aparcaBicicletas, leo un archivo que contiene los datos de los aparcabicicletas, los datos que contiene el archivo son:
5.995101982988274,37.38900094875865,36,CASCO_ANTIGUO,4,SI
5.976952420987936,37.394906910666272,37,SAN PABLO_SANTA JUSTA,5,SI
5.984378793441746,37.381021630040884,43,NERVION,6,SI
5.994268346404604,37.397079331127095,44,CASCO_ANTIGUO,7,SI
6.008781528134852,37.403286511420987,45,TRIANA,6,SI
5.987673813903903,37.365865796207714,1,BELLAVISTA_LA PALMERA,5,SI
5.984516235680223,37.399101823666975,16,CASCO_ANTIGUO,5,SI
5.971849990174137,37.420642905776361,28,MACARENA_NORTE,3,SI
5.986856346995355,37.399116096532588,17,CASCO_ANTIGUO,11,SI
5.989313239297421,37.398184786353404,18,CASCO_ANTIGUO,5,SI
5.989712989598854,37.36399876830852,3,BELLAVISTA_LA PALMERA,3,SI
5.98696594146001,37.363689615420029,5,BELLAVISTA_LA PALMERA,6,SI
5.990761323535414,37.395145280507116,19,CASCO_ANTIGUO,3,SI
5.969343690531444,37.42291017796061,25,MACARENA_NORTE,3,NO
5.968788531685851,37.422107580018007,26,MACARENA_NORTE,3,SI
5.999120147254147,37.388126612743413,27,CASCO_ANTIGUO,4,SI
5.974161355400184,37.398237596588778,35,SAN PABLO_SANTA JUSTA,6,SI

Entonces lo que hago es dividir los datos por coma con .split y con el array ir formando el objeto, no entiendo por que me sale ese error en todo lo que tiene Aparcabicicletas, no tiene sentido. No he probado con otros ides porque no se como va esto en otros, pero lo probaré.

esta es la clase GestionAparcaBicicletas.java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class GestionAparcabicicletas {
    private Set<Aparcabicicletas>coleccionAparcabicicletas;
    
    
    public GestionAparcabicicletas() {
        coleccionAparcabicicletas = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length>0){
            cargaDatos(args);
        }
    }

    private void anadirAparcaBicicleta(Aparcabicicletas a){
        coleccionAparcabicicletas.add(a);
    }


    private void imprimirListadoNombre(){
        for(Aparcabicicletas a: coleccionAparcabicicletas)
            System.out.println(a);
    }

    private void imprimirListadoId(){
        for(Aparcabicicletas a: coleccionAparcabicicletas)
            System.out.println(a.toStringId());
    }


    private static void cargaDatos(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);

        GestionAparcabicicletas gestion = new GestionAparcabicicletas();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Aparcabicicletas aparcabicicletas = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            String cadena;
            String[]palabras;
            
            while((cadena=br.readLine())!=null){
                palabras = cadena.split(",");
                double x = Double.parseDouble(palabras[0]);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(palabras[1]);
                int id = Integer.parseInt(palabras[2]);
                String barrios = palabras[3];
                int aros = Integer.parseInt(palabras[4]);
                String instalado = palabras[5];

                aparcabicicletas = new Aparcabicicletas(x, y, id, barrios, aros, instalado);
                gestion.anadirAparcaBicicleta(aparcabicicletas);

                System.out.println("*******LISTADO POR NOMBRE***********");
                gestion.imprimirListadoNombre();
                System.out.println("*********LISTADO POR ID***************");
                gestion.imprimirListadoId();    
            }         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }finally{
            try {
                if(br!=null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error al cerrar fichero");
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Por lo que se ve, te falta hacer el método `main` en `GestionAparcabicicletas`.

Comment: Hola Jorge, vamos por partes,  texto en imágenes **no**, tanto código como mensajes de error, **siempre** como texto, el problema... hago pregunta el comentario de @GavilanPatagonico, tiene método **main** tu clase **GestionAparcabicicletas**?, si si, tu programa esta en un `jar`?, si si debes ejecutarlo con **java -jar GestionAparcabicicletas**, si no, compilaste antes de ejecutar con **javac GestionAparcabicicletas AparcaBicicletas ComparadorAparcaBicicletasBarrio etc**?, si no... estamos jodidos jaja.

Comment: Tengo hecho el método main, además de que el error se produce en las clases AparcaBicicletas.

Comment: Se supone que le tengo que pasar esto por terminal java GestionAparcabicicletas aparcabicicletas.csv y lo que tiene que hacer el ejercicio es leerme el archivo aparcabicicletas.csv, que me lo lee bien y lo divido en strings para guardarlo en un array e ir creando objetos de la clase AparcaBicicletas, pero parece como que no detecta la clase porque el error se me lanza ahí.

Comment: Y si compilan, es decir puedo hacer javac de todas las clases perfectamente

Comment: Nop, el error que te marca es que no encuentra la clase principal, **GestionAparcabicicletas**, entonces pasamos a la segunda parte, tu programa está en un jar?

Comment: Ya se me ha arreglado y funciona.

Comment: Al hacer el .class parece que ha funcionado

Comment: Buenísimo Genio!!!

Comment: Era porque no tenía hecho el .class, entonces estaba intentando ejecutar clases de java que no estaban compiladas. Muchas gracias a MarcePuente que ha sido el que me ha dado una gran pista para saber que podría estar mal y a todos los demás también.